# Cancel editor collection of Propertygrid not through UI

Tags: c#, propertygrid, collectioneditor

I saw that in order to cancel the collection editor need to set type as follows:

```
public class MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyCollectionEditor(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public class MyCollection : CollectionBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    //...
}
```

You can find it at the following link (In answer to the question of Alan Seedhouse's):

**[Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert?msg=3253299#xx3253299xx)**

My problem is that I do not define the `MyCollection.cs` in UI (but in class library) and therefore I can not inherit from `CollectionEditor`.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked like this:

```
public class MyCollectionEditor : UITypeEditor
{ 
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
    }
}
```